# Is it valid to cross-validate linear regression models out of chronological order in a time series context?

Tags: regression, time-series, cross-validation

For simplicity I'll stick to the univariate case with one exogenous regressor. Suppose I have

X = (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>)

Y = (y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, ..., y<sub>n</sub>)

where i < j indicates x<sub>i</sub> came before x<sub>j</sub> chronologically, and likewise for y<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>j</sub>, regardless of the unit of time, for 1 <= i < j <= n.

Leaving aside the usual caveats about the interpretability of a regression model fitted to time series data, is there anything philosophically incorrect about cross-validating my linear regression trained on these data out of order? For example, is it sound to do leave-one-out cross-validation with (x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k</sub>) as the test set, incorporating data (x<sub>t</sub>, y<sub>t</sub>) in the training set for t > k?

Given linear regression's distributional assumptions of linearity and constant variance, the order of the exogenous and endogenous coordinates doesn't matter within the same training set as long as pairwise indices are preserved (i.e. the ranks are kept the same, x<sub>k</sub> is only matched to y<sub>k</sub> and not some other y<sub>i</sub>).

It seems to follow that there should be no advantage to requiring that the test data strictly come after the training data for linear regression in particular, which has no notion of time or temporal order, if we are already making these distributional assumptions.

Comment: This has been studied before. See e.g. [section 5.10 of "Forecasting Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html) and ["Cross-validation for time series"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/) and the top 2 hits (at least for me) on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=time+series+cross+validation&btnG=) (both by Bergmeir et al.).

Comment: Yes I have read Hyndman's work before; it's very good! But what I am suggesting is different. Instead of thinking about time series models in general, think about regression specifically. My assertion is that, if you are already using regression on time series data, there is no point to enforcing that all train data chronologically predates test data. Either you are fulfilling the assumptions of linear regression and all the data follow the same distribution, or you are not fulfilling that assumptions and the model is undermined from the get go.

Comment: From the abstract of Bergmeir et al. (2018) linked above: *It is shown that for purely autoregressive models, the use of standard K-fold CV is possible **provided the models considered have uncorrelated errors**.* So your logic seems to work as long as some assumptions are satisfied. For models that have a decent balance between overfitting and underfitting / a decent bias-variance tradeoff, I would assume nonzero but low autocorrelation in the errors, so the assumptions would be mildly violated.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume that your model is incorrect (as it always is).  Let's also assume that there is some systematic trend in the data, and that you omit the some observations in the middle of the data, choosing to train on data from the start and end of the process.

You risk having your model seem like it can predict the data better than it should in this case.  Because there is a systematic trend, the model will pick up that and your cross validation is really evaluating your model's ability to *interpolate* when you want to use the model to *extrapolate*.

Your validation strategy should reflect the way the model is to be used.  If you're using the model to extrapolate, then the validation strategy should be a sort of extrapolation.

Comment: Linear regression already assumes there is _no_ systematic trend in the data. This is part of the distributional assumptions I mentioned. So I would rather we _not_ assume a systematic trend, because that's part of the exercise.

Mathematically speaking, given the definition of regression (and regardless of how it is used or misused), how can it be that the order of validation matters? It seems like you're saying that regression just shouldn't be used on time series data, which I think is fair but separate to what I'm trying to get at here as an exercise in assumptions.

Comment: In other words let's say we are satisfying the assumption of homoskedasticity for linear regression already, and ask the question in that light.

Comment: @phdont That is *not* what linear regression assumes.  Indeed, if you don't think that some covariate explains variation in the outcome, why perform a linear regression at all?  I've already explained that assessing the model by placing it in similar scenarios in which it will be used is the goal of validation.  The mathematical details of the model are irrelevant to this point.